# Fade in/out Android ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm using the AppCompat ActionBar (Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) for my Android app.

After starting the app, the ActionBar fades out after 6 seconds (onCreate method):

```
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}, 6000);
```

So, how can I fade in the ActionBar with a touch gesture from the top of the screen to the middle ... and fade out it again after 10 seconds?

[image]

I think the problem is, that the ActionBar has no OnTouchListener.

Comment: You could use `onTouchEvent()` on your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
In the class you want to use the gesture:

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

     //Stuff in onCreate()

}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        //Swipe from the top to the bottom
        if(event2.getY() > event1.getY()){

            getSupportActionBar().show();

            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                }
             }, 6000);

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a method to check, if the dropdown menu of the actionbar is opend? I want to abort fading out, if the dropdown menu is opened

Comment: @Maddy try using a boolean variable: when you open the dropdown menu set it as true, when you close it set it as false, and add a condition to `getSupportActionBar().hide()` to avoid executing it when the variable is true.

Comment: but how can I detect, that the dropdown menu is opened?

Comment: @Maddy, when you open it, you must click somewhere, or do something, change the state of the boolean variable when you do that action. E.g. if it opens clicking on an icon, put `variable = true` inside onClick